# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process 478 exceeded cursor quota 100, will kill it

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

I just want load all my phone's contacts, below is the source code. I have also closed the cursor, i don't know why this error happen, there anyone could tell me what reason could cause this error and how to fix it .

```
Cursor cursor = null;
try {
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    cursor = mActivity.getContentResolver().query(uri,new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY }, null, null, null);

    while (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String number = cursor.getString(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String id = cursor.getString(2);
        String key = cursor.getString(3);

        number = Utils.trimTelNum(number);

        LogUtil.i(TAG, "contacts number=" + number + ",name=" + name);

            if (number == null || name == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "contacts name or number is null,continue");
                continue;
            }
            CalllogBean bean = new CalllogBean();
            bean.setContactId(id);
            bean.setNumber(number);
            bean.setContactName(name);
            bean.setLookupKey(key);
            contactsMap.put(number, bean);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // close the cursor
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
            cursor = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you at least look for the meaning of the exception to see what it means?

Comment: It that means the cursor create over than 100?